# Copy A table to another Table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two Table

one is `student_record_temp`

| id | name | roll |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Shadman | 2 |
| 2 | Adnan | 3 |

Now I want to copy the row in `student_record` where the name is shadman and it returns both `student_record_temp` and `student_record` `id`

I am trying to solve this in

```
INSERT INTO student_record (name,rool) select name,roll from student_record_temp 
FROM student_record_temp WHERE name='shadman' RETURNING student_record.id,student_record_temp.id
```

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "student_record_temp"
LINE 8: student_record.id,student_record_temp.id
```

but I got an error and how I can solve this.

Comment: I do not understand the part you are saying "it returns both student_record_temp and student_record id"

Comment: Actually, I want, the id of both tables.

Comment: you are inserting into student_record table so there is no such row in that table hence no id in student_record  table

Answer (score 1):

To copy a table with partial data from an existing table

CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT
*
FROM
existing_table
WHERE
condition;
The condition in the WHERE clause of the query defines which rows of the existing table will be copied to the new table

or you can use this:

INSERT INTO TABLE1 (id, col_1, col_2, col_3)
SELECT id, 'data1', 'data2', 'data3'
FROM TABLE2
WHERE col_a = 'something';

Answer (score 1):

You can't be returning data from select in the insert query. You can use two scenarios:

- **second scenario**
  If `name` column data from `student_record_temp` table is unique. you can use join in returning query:

```sql
insert into student_record as sr (name, roll)
select srt.name, srt.roll
from student_record_temp srt
where name = 'shadman'
returning sr.id, (select id from student_record_temp r_srt where r_srt.name = sr.name);
```

- **first scenario**
  If `name` column data from `student_record_temp` table is not unique. you have to create temp unique field and use from that

```sql
with select_data as (
    select srt.id, srt.name, srt.roll, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
    from student_record_temp srt
    where name = 'shadman'),
     add_data as (
         insert into student_record as sr (name, roll)
             select sd.name, sd.roll
             from select_data sd
             order by sd.id
             returning sr.id)
select ad.id as insert_id,
       sd.id as select_id
from (select id, row_number() over (order by id) as rn from add_data) ad
         inner join select_data sd on ad.rn = sd.rn;
```